# SQL Group By With Fragmentation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this data

```
   UserId   DepartmentId      LoginDate
    100          1            2022-03-01
    101          2            2022-03-01     
    102          2            2022-04-05
    103          3            2022-04-05
    104          3            2022-04-05
    105          1            2022-06-07
```

and I need this output

```
LoginDate     TotalPerson    Dep1Person  Dep2Person  Dep3Person  
2022-03-01         2             1            1          0
2022-04-05         3             0            1          2
2022-06-07         1             1            0          0
```

I know using group by with count. But also I need each department persons count. Could you help me about SQL query.

Comment: Search for PIVOT

Comment: What is your current attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `case` to take care of different `DepartmentId`.

**Schema SQL**

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  UserId INT,
  DepartmentId INT,
  LoginDate DATE
);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (100, 1, '2022-03-01');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (101, 2, '2022-03-01');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (102, 2, '2022-04-05');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (103, 3, '2022-04-05');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (104, 3, '2022-04-05');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (105, 1, '2022-06-07');
```

**Query SQL**

```
SELECT 
LoginDate, 
COUNT(*) AS TotalPerson,
SUM(CASE DepartmentId WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Dep1Person,
SUM(CASE DepartmentId WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Dep2Person,
SUM(CASE DepartmentId WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Dep3Person
FROM test
GROUP BY LoginDate
```

---

**Result**

| LoginDate | TotalPerson | Dep1Person | Dep2Person | Dep3Person |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-01 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2022-04-05 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 2022-06-07 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

---

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bXkzNxRt21bevEWg9gHH5n/0

Comment: A good answer explains what is happening in addition to having a working solution.

Comment: Normally we use `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(1)` instead of `SUM(1)` to count rows